# How do I have to code my code so the text appears in the Circle and not outside of it?

Tags: html, css

So I have this problem where I have a Circle and when I wanna write something in the circle it starts outside of the Circle.
I think it's because it was a block before but I just made it into circle with `border-radius: 50%`.
How should i write my code so the Text appears in the circle?

```css
#m {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: forestgreen;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="m">
  <p>bla bla bla</p>
</div>
```

I hope u guys can help me :D

Answer (score 2):

Can use flex to center to the text.

```css
#m {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: forestgreen;
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="m">
  <p>bla bla bla</p>
</div>
```

If you want to get really crazy with it and have more text I recommend [this article](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-to-set-text-inside-a-circle/) which uses `shape-outside` to wrap the text within the circle.

Comment: A good reading about [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: appreciate you brother

Comment: This is nice for a small amount of text (i.e. that you know is going to fit) but under the skin the div is still a rectangle and with a lot of text you will get text outside the circle. Does anyone know of a good way to force the text to stay in the circle (ie short lines at the top, getting longer towards the center)?

Answer (score 0):

I added these 3 lines to your style:

```
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
```

Which you can see the result of below.

```css
#m {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: forestgreen;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div  id="m"><p>bla bla bla</p></div>
```

Comment: appreciate you bro :DD